# Does SQL Server propagate WHERE conditions in complex views?

Tags: sql-server, view, sqlperformance

I've followed this question with a full example in case it isn't clear what I mean from the question.

I've made a view which joins data from about five tables.  The tables have vast amounts of data and the queries are slow to run.  My question is that if I do:

```
SELECT * FROM myView WHERE PersonID = 1000
```

does SQL Server 'know what I mean' and automatically propagate that condition to the underlying joins in the view?  So that it doesn't run for *everybody*, but minimizes the result set at the right stages.  Or will it run for everything then do the `WHERE ID = 1000` on the full result set?

---

**AN EXAMPLE**

To simplify (...hopefully) what I mean, here's an example pseudo-TSQL scenario:

```
TABLE People (
    ID,
    Surname,
    DOB
)
TABLE Activities (
    ID,
    TypeID,
    LocationID,
    Date
)
TABLE PersonActivityInvolvements (
    ID, 
    PersonID, 
    ActivityID
)
TABLE ActivityTypes (
    ID,
    Name
)
TABLE Locations (
    ID,
    Street,
    City
)
```

So I want a view which shows me all `People`, any `Activities` they were involved in, the  `ActivityType`, and the `Location` it took place.  Although this setup is not drastically complicated, you can see that it might take a very long time to execute if there are say tens of thousands of each entity.

The view might be something like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    People LEFT OUTER JOIN PersonActivityInvolvement PA
    ON People.ID = PA.ID
        INNER JOIN Activity 
        ON PA.ID = Activity.ID
            INNER JOIN ActivityTypes AT
            ON A.TypeID = AT.ID
                INNER JOIN Locations 
                ON A.LocationID = Locations.ID
```

So if was to do

```
SELECT * FROM myView WHERE DOB >= dateAdd(YEAR, -18, getDate())
```

would the query inside the view run for everyone or would SQL Server know that it should apply it to the `People.DOB` field?

Comment: This is easily testable using SQL Server Query Analyzer.  Show the execution plan and look at the filter applied to the tables.  If it shows the where condition being applied, then it is transitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The engine will do whatever it thinks is fastest.  If you have that field indexed, and your `JOIN` keys are all indexed, it may or may not run that filter first.

It may actually run the filter LAST if the `WHERE` clause is more expensive (i.e. unindexed) - that way the expensive operation is running on the smallest result set.

Ther only way to know for sure is to run the query and check the execution plan (**ACTUAL** not estimated).

Answer (score 3):

This is called predicate pushing.

SQL Server is generally good at this though there are some constructs where there have been problems (e.g. see the final part of [this article](http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2010/03/performance-tuning-101-what-you-will_17.html)).

Check the execution plan to see where the predicate is applied.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the optimizer will handle this with aplomb, but as the query and implied subqueries become increasingly complex, the chances that the optimizer will choose the proper execution path diminishes accordingly.  This can be aggravated by having more indexes on the tables, or very similar indexes on the tables it will be examining.

As a general rule, I try to discourage joining to views, and I strongly discourage creating views that are comprised of other views.